# How to find the PID of a open program

Tags: vb.net, process, pid

I am trying to figure out how to find the PID, of for example notepad.exe. I have googled this, and I found lots of stuff, but I can't quite unterstand it. I've tried this code:

```
Dim currentProcess As Process = Process.GetCurrentProcess()
Dim localAll As Process() = Process.GetProcesses()
Dim localByName As Process() = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad")
Label1.Text = localByName.ToString
```

But when executed, I get **`system.diagnostics.process[]`** as output in `label1`. I am quite noob in vb.net still, and can't seem to find the problem here.

Comment: This question was asked yesterday by a different user. Interesting this question popped up again by a different username...and word for word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetProcessesByName returns an array.  You may have multiple Notepads running, but here is how you'd get the id of the first.

```
Dim currentProcess As Process = Process.GetCurrentProcess()
Dim localAll As Process() = Process.GetProcesses()
Dim localByName As Process() = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad")

'Do this
Label1.Text = localByName(0).Id
```

or

```
'Find all!
for each proc in localByName
   Label1.Text &= proc.Id & vbCrLf 'vbCrlf just adds a new line for reading purposes
next
```